# Access VBA to export data based on query into a xlsx template that is predesigned to accept exported data

Tags: mysql, excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Currently, we are able to build reports in Access. However, they want that same report built in Excel.  These reports are regulated and need to be designed to specifications. I have designed the Excel template(workbook) with one tab having the Report and another tab having the data. Desired outcome: User would click a button to export the data. Open the pre-designed Excel template, populate the data tab, save the Excel file with specific name in predefined directory, view the report on the report tab.  Below is what I have constructed so far and is only able to create a new file not use the pre-designed Excel Template. Actually, this code does not work right now. Any suggestions or tutelage would be greatly appreciated. :-)

```
Private Sub Button_ExhP2_XLSX_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim mysql As String
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Create filepath for data to be saved in
Const xlsxPath = "\\Path\Access dBase\O-Blank Exhibits\"

'Create Filname used to save data to excel
FileName = "BlankPart2 " & [Forms]![Frm_Main]![Frm_Main_ListBox_BU] & "_" & [Forms]![Frm_Main]![Frm_Main_Combo_Qtr] & "_" & [Forms]![Frm_Main]![Frm_Main_Combo_Year]

'Delete file if it already exists so it may fully be replaced with new data
If fso.FileExists(xlsxPath & FileName & ".xlsx") Then
    Kill xlsxPath & FileName & ".xlsx"
End If

 'Pull detail based on Part 2
  mysql = ""
  mysql = mysql + " SELECT "
  mysql = mysql + " BSTimePeriod, "
  mysql = mysql + " ISTimePeriod, "
  mysql = mysql + " Fiscal_Quarter, "
  mysql = mysql + " Year, "
  mysql = mysql + " BU, "
  mysql = mysql + " BU_Description, "
  mysql = mysql + " OU, "
  mysql = mysql + " OU_Description, "
  mysql = mysql + " P2_Category, "
  mysql = mysql + " P2_Line, "
  mysql = mysql + " Comp, "
  mysql = mysql + " FEP, "
  mysql = mysql + " Med, "
  mysql = mysql + " CHP, "
  mysql = mysql + " FHP, "
  mysql = mysql + " Total, "
  mysql = mysql + " Order, "
  mysql = mysql + " Balance, "
  mysql = mysql + " FROM dbo_P2_Exh_Analytic_Rpt "
  mysql = mysql + " WHERE (((dbo_P2_Exh_Analytic_Rpt.Fiscal_Quarter)='" & [Forms]!  [Frm_Main]![Frm_Main_Combo_Qtr] & "') "
  mysql = mysql + " AND ((dbo_P2_Exh_Analytic_Rpt.Year)='" & [Forms]![Frm_Main]![Frm_Main_Combo_Year] & "') "
  mysql = mysql + " AND ((dbo_P2_Exh_Analytic_Rpt.BU)='" & [Forms]![Frm_Main]![Frm_Main_ListBox_BU] & "')) "
  DoCmd.RunSQL mysql

'Open record set create for Part 2
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(mysql, dbOpenDynaset)

'export summary detail file to excel
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "Orange Part 2", xlsxPath & FileName & ".xlsx", True
 Set db = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox ("BlankPart 2 data has been exported.")
'additional comments: error may occur if Category doesn't exist in dbo.MTest_Sums,    didn't build error trap because wasn't sure if this could happen
End Sub
```

The error is: Compile Error: Variable Not found
`Set db = CurrentDb` is highlighted

Comment: In *what way* does this code "not work right now"?  The `DoCmd.RunSQL MySQL` line seems pointless, as `DoCmd.RunSQL` is intended for executing action queries, not `SELECT` queries.

Comment: @Monty Wild I am trying to piece something together with what I have found and presume that it has code as you mentioned that is pointless. Error is below->
Compile Error: Variable Not found
Set db = is highlighted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be receiving a compile error if you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

You would need to add `DIM db as DAO.Database` above the offending line to correct this.

Also, if you are connecting to a MySQL database, I doubt that you should be using `Set db = CurrentDb`, but rather you should be using some variant on `Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase()` where the `name` contains a reference to the MySQL DSN. Have a look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/HV080753920.aspx for more details.

Comment: The user should accept this answer and entrust his remaining issues to a future, separate post.  Then I guess we should declare this post `duplicate` or `unenlightening typo issue`.  But I sound awful hard on T-Rex; the post is a good honest one and hopefully a lesson learned.